# Split each item from one list into a 2d list with a key value pair

Tags: python, list

I have multiple lists that differ in length. All items are floats. I want to take each item from the list and split it into a 2d list as a key value pair. Example, `lst = [13.45, 15.46, 17.98, 14.98]`
should become `two_d_lst = [[0, 13.45], [1, 15.46], [2, 17.98], [3, 14.98]]` what is the most pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension (most pythonic way to do this):

```
lst = [13.45, 15.46, 17.98, 14.98]
two_d_lst = [[i,j] for i,j in enumerate(lst)]

print(two_d_lst)
[[0, 13.45], [1, 15.46], [2, 17.98], [3, 14.98]]
```

P.S: `2d_lst` is not a valid name